# Error loading plugin manager: null on GGTS 3.4.0

Tags: grails

after entering the following command in GGTS 3.4.0:

```
generate-controller org.strotmann.fahrauftraege.Fahrauftrag
```

I get:

```
Loading Grails 2.2.4
Configuring classpath.
Environment set to development.....
Packaging Grails application.....
Packaging Grails application..... Error
  Error loading plugin manager: null
```

Comment: What happens if you run the command on the command line? `grails generate-controller org.strotmann.fahrauftraege.Fahrauftrag`

Comment: peter@ubuntu-pangolin:~$ cd workspaces/fahrauftraege/fahrauftraege
peter@ubuntu-pangolin:~/workspaces/fahrauftraege/fahrauftraege$ grails generate-all fahrauftraege.Fahrauftrag
| Packaging Grails application.....
| Error Error loading plugin manager: null (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
peter@ubuntu-pangolin:~/workspaces/fahrauftraege/fahrauftraege$

Comment: it works, if I use plain grails on the linux console for everything: create-app, create-domain, generate-all, run-app, using ggts (3.4.0 or 3.5.1) it does not work at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you launch your GGTS using Java 8 then try launching it using Java 7 (specify -vm parameter in STS.ini). Ensure that in Preferences Java -> Installed JRE Java 7 JRE is present and selected (not Java 8). Make sure the Groovy compiler setting is appropriate for Grails 2.2.4. Also you can try deleting .metadata folder from your workspace (essentially to wipe out launch conifgs), reimport your Grails project, create a lunch config for it and launch it.